# Rules in views for custom user types

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

in my app I created two types of users by one-to-one relations.

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(AuthUser, primary_key=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(AuthUser, primary_key=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

in views now I'm checking user role as follows:

```
student = Student.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
teacher = Teacher.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
```

but it throws an exception, which better way should I use it?

for example: if in view I get student by token, but I pasted teacher's token I get:

```
500:
DoesNotExist at /create/
Student matching query does not exist.
```

Comment: It throws an error that says something like 'not found?'

Comment: Could you show us the error?

Answer (score 0):

i think it is on your lookup parameters and data you wan't to search by id user is not to user id instead but into id of student and teacher, try to this code:

```
student = Student.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id)
teacher = Teacher.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id)
```

for thrown this error

```
500:
DoesNotExist at /create/
Student matching query does not exist.
```

because the data you want to find by id is not found